# Can't import 'foreign' disk because "a disk group with the specified name already exists"

Tags: windows-xp, hard-drive

I have multiple hard drives. One for programs (C:) and one for data (D:).

My plan was to install Windows 7 on a new SSD drive which would replace my current (C:). Windows 7 wouldn't install onto the SSD for an unrelated reason. So back to XP.

However, when I booted back to XP my data drive (D:) (which I didn't touch) now shows up as a 'Foreign' (Dynamic) disk in Disk Management.

When I try to import the foreign disk, the dialog shows the single partition as 'OK', but when I click OK, I get an error.

This is the error from the system log:

```
Event Type: Error
Event Source:   LDM
Event Category: None
Event ID:   2
Date:       11/23/2009
Time:       11:28:47 PM
User:       N/A
Computer:   SILENTBOB
Description:
INTERNAL Error - A disk group with the specified name already exists  (C100007A).
```

And just prior to that error, is this warning:

```
Event Type: Warning
Event Source:   LDM
Event Category: None
Event ID:   1000
Date:       11/23/2009
Time:       11:28:47 PM
User:       N/A
Computer:   SILENTBOB
Description:
Disk group SilentbobDg0: Two disk groups have the same name
```

The disk won't import.

How can I fix this? Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To work around this issue, we need to modify registry.
If you use Registry Editor incorrectly, you may cause
serious problems that may require you to reinstall your
operating system. Microsoft cannot guarantee that you can
solve problems that result from using Registry Editor
incorrectly.

If your system/boot drive is still a basic disk, follow
these steps to correct this
condition:

1. Start Registry Editor (Regedt32.exe).
2. Click the following registry key:

   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\dmio\Boot Info
3. Under the Boot Info key, delete the "Primary Disk Group" key.(you need to delete the CORRECT key for your DISK)
4. Quit Registry Editor, and then reboot the computer.
5. After the reboot, try to import the foreign disks again.

Source: [Cannot import foreign disks!](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/thread-472161.php)

Please try the suggestion above and let me know the results.

Comment: That fixed it. Thank you. After deleting the "Primary Disk Group" and rebooting, the disk automatically showed up (no import required). This worked for my dynamic disk even though the steps above say "is still a basic disk".

Comment: no Problem!!  glad it worked!